Using pgTAP, can i select values/records into variables to use in the test?
I have a test factory function that creates and returns single records:
CREATE FUNCTION build_rec_for_test()
RETURNS mytable
AS $$
   INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (rand_uuid(),rand_int(),rand_int()) RETURNING *;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

Is there a way to easily use that return value in pgTAP?
I'm basically looking to treat the return value as a variable, but maybe I'm too locked in the "regular" procedural style of thought.
A DO block is not useful - it does not write to stdout (link).
I'd like to do something like
BEGIN;
SELECT plan(1);

DECLARE my_rec = build_rec_for_test();

-- perform a test with values from the factory function
SELECT is(SELECT id FROM mytable, my_rec.id); 

SELECT * FROM finish();
ROLLBACK;

A more complete example might be something like
BEGIN;
SELECT plan(1);

DECLARE author = create_mock_author();
DECLARE post1 = create_mock_post_for(author);
DECLARE post2 = create_mock_post_for(author);
DECLARE comment1 = create_mock_comment_for(post1);
DECLARE comment2 = create_mock_comment_for(post2);

-- perform a test with values from the factory function
SELECT is(
    SELECT status FROM comments WHERE id = comment1.id, 
    'IN_REVIEW'
); 

-- I realize this is not a good test, because create_mock_post_for
-- will set the value, but it's an example of using an intermediate
-- record as part of the test
SELECT is(
    SELECT author_id FROM posts WHERE id = post1.id,
    author.id
);

SELECT * FROM finish();
ROLLBACK;

But obviously, that's not valid syntax.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

SELECT is(SELECT id FROM mytable, select id from build_rec_for_test());?

Right, that works, but i'd potentially like to use my_rec for more than a single check. Or build a different set of records based on that record. Maybe build a record in a parent table, and several different records for several child tables. Stuff like that.

Then to your question add a complete description of what you want with examples.

Updated with a more complete example - thanks for looking!


Your updated example makes no sense, if for no other reason then you don't actually use the build_rec_for_test() like you claim:  --perform a test with values from the factory function 2) Pretty sure once you create an correct outline of what you want it can be handled in a DO function.


Sure, it's a different example, using the canonical example of a blog system, with authors, posts as children of authors, and comments as children of posts. I will not actually use this code, these are just intended for illustration of what I'm attempting to accomplish.  DO blocks are not useful (See https://groups.google.com/g/pgtap-users/c/UgytyzBnXOc/m/qcb942UABgAJ), as they don't output anything, so pgTAP cannot parse the output. I am able to declare these variables in a DO block, but cannot use them with pgTAP.

DO blocks don't return values, but you can create a temporary PL/pgSQL function that RETURNS SETOF TEXT, have it RETURN NEXT reach pgTAP function call, and call it.

@theory I took this advice - seems to work great! I'll put my answer below, but if you want the SO points, feel free to put an answer in.

All yours, @Hoopes.

This appears to work nicely:
BEGIN;
SELECT plan(2);

CREATE FUNCTION test_schema.test1()
RETURNS SETOF TEXT
AS $$
DECLARE
  parent1 parent_type;
  parent2 parent_type;
  child1 child_type;
  child2 child_type;
BEGIN

  SELECT * INTO parent1 FROM create_mock_parent();
  SELECT * INTO parent2 FROM create_mock_parent();
  SELECT * INTO child1 FROM create_mock_child(parent_id := parent1.id);
  SELECT * INTO child2 FROM create_mock_child(parent_id := parent2.id);

  RETURN QUERY SELECT is(parent1.id, child1.parent_id);
  RETURN QUERY SELECT is(parent2.id, child2.parent_id);

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM test_schema.test1();

SELECT * FROM finish();
ROLLBACK;


I've been dying for something like this, thank you!
